# Javascript loading

Tags: javascript, twitter, loading

I noticed an error, when Twitter was down like 20 minutes a few days ago. In some browsers, my page wouldn't entirely load, because it couldn't load the twitter feed. Of course, I don't want my uptime to be depending on the uptime of Twitter so I want to fix this. When I checked out the code of my wordpress theme I found that it's loading javascript on the middle of the page. That's why it probably got stuck, since it couldn't download the right files? Here is the code:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $username ?>" class="twitter-link"></a>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/<?php echo $username ?>.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=<?php echo $postcount ?>"></script>
```

Of course there is a lot more code to this widget, but I believe this is the important part. Can I split this up that the loading is done at the bottom of the page? That way the visitor can still see my webpage right?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to load the scripts at the end of the head tag, perhaps - good question!

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs so his users will see a blank page instead of half a page ?

Comment: Either that or put it at the end of the body - One script shouldn't hold the the whole page up, should it?

Comment: If you put it on the bottom of the `body` the page will load (mostly) but the document ready still won't fire. The only way to make sure your page will fully work independent of 3-rd party scripts is to load them dynamically after your page is loaded (after document ready).

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding either the `async` or `defer` attributes to your `<script>` elements.

e.g.

```
<script async src="..."></script>
```

or

```
<script defer src="..."></script>
```

If you prefer XHTML:

```
<script async="async" src="..."></script>
```

or

```
<script defer="defer" src="..."></script>
```